# split output after date

Tags: python, dictionary, split, whitespace

I have a script that outputs my tasks in this format:

```
Thu Apr 04           Finish Work
                     Walk

Sat Apr 06           Collect NIC

Mon Apr 08           Run test
```

I want to split it into a dictionary so I can do some matching/formatting:

```
{'Thu Apr 04' : ('Finish Work', 'Walk'),
'Sat Apr 06' : 'Collect NIC',
'Mon Apr 08' : 'Run test'}
```

I've tried string funcs like split(), replace() but I can't get the format I want.

**UPDATE # 1**

I assigned the output of the script to a variable and used `print repr(output)` which gives:

```
'\nThu Apr 04           Finish PTI Video\n                     Weigh In\n\nSat Apr 06           Collect NIC\n\nMon Apr 08           Serum uric acid test\n\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
a = '\nThu Apr 04           Finish PTI Video\n                     Weigh In\n                         Eat out\n\nSat Apr 06           Collect NIC\n\nMon Apr 08           Serum uric acid        test\n\n'
b = {}
same_day = ''
for x in a.split('\n'):
    c = x.split('           ')
    if c[0] is '':
        for q in c:
            if q is not '':
                b.update({same_day: b[same_day] + ', ' + q.strip()})
                break
    else:
        same_day = c[0]
        b.update({c[0] : c[1]})
```

Its dirty. But will get the job done.
If the input is a file then you can do a readline to get x

Comment: returns a index out of range error for the last line. I've updated the question which might help you get a better idea of the output the script is presenting.

Comment: if i add a `print c` statement after `c = x.split('     ')` I get:
`['']
['Thu Apr 04           Finish PTI Video']
['                     Weigh In']
['']
['Sat Apr 06           Collect NIC']
['']
['Mon Apr 08           Serum uric acid test']
['']
['']`

Comment: oops! my bad. I did a replace spaces by tabs in my editor which screwed up the `c = x.split('        ')` line. Your code works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the output of your original script (that is, the example text you want to parse) saved in a file called "schedule.txt."

```
import re
with open("schedule.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
sched = {}
currday = None
for line in lines:
    newday = re.match(r'(\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)\s+(.*)',line)
    if newday:
        currday = newday.group(1)
        sched[currday] = [newday.group(2)]
    elif currday:
        newact = re.match(r'\s+(.*)',line)
        if newact:
            sched[currday] = newact.group(1)
```

Note that this will save entries as lists, not tuples. If you really need tuples, though, you can just call the `tuple()` function on them.